# persistence.xml not found on glassfish deployment descriptor (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish-3, persistence.xml

I have an EJB and a WEB module in my IntelliJ, created 5 entities that I would hope to load into a database using annotations.

I go to project settings, under modules, and select that I want to add JPA facet, I know have a EJB, WEB and JPA facet. I use eclipselink, so I checked that under JPA settings, I then added my persistence.xml file, configured the file.

Problem is that when deploying, it simply will not deploy the persistence.xml file, which means I can not find it under my glassfish 3.0 server when selecting my application under deployment descriptors. I only find my sun-web-ejb.xml under the EJB module. persistence.xml is not under the WEB module either, but I assume it should be under the EJB module anyway.

Is it intended that my persistence.xml should not be loaded on the server so that I can find the xml file under GF admin console (applications -> EJB module of mine -> deployment descriptors) ?

If this is not intended, is there anything in particular I need to do in IntelliJ to make persistence.xml being deployed on server? Maybe its something in particular I need to do with my JPA facet?

Thank you for any feedback on this, I can ofcourse provide more detailed information about my setup if neccessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only find my sun-web-ejb.xml under the EJB module.

That's already weird. If I'm not wrong, this is a proprietary deployment descriptor for the Web module.

> persistence.xml is not under the WEB module either, but I assume it should be under the EJB module anyway

It all depends on how you package and deploy your entities, which can be done in several ways (see [What You May Need to Know About Persistence Unit Packaging Options](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Packaging_and_Deploying_EclipseLink_JPA_Applications_%28ELUG%29#What_You_May_Need_to_Know_About_Persistence_Unit_Packaging_Options)).

If your entities are packaged in an EJB-JAR, the `persistence.xml` must be placed in the  `META-INF` directory.

But you could package them inside the Web module, this would be simpler in your case. See the above link.

> Is it intended that my persistence.xml should not be loaded on the server so that I can find the xml file under GF admin console (applications -> EJB module of mine -> deployment descriptors)?

I suggest to check that the physical JAR contains the `META-INF/persistence.xml`.

> If this is not intended, is there anything in particular I need to do in IntelliJ to make persistence.xml being deployed on server? Maybe its something in particular I need to do with my JPA facet?

Can't say. Maybe the following link could help: [Enabling JPA Support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-jpa-support.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you where right, it depends how I packaged it, so in my case the persistence.xml should not be listed on my GF 3.0 server. 
Also I want to thank you for some other posts you made regarding EE development, I went and looked at your profile, and saw you recommended a book with JavaEE 6 platform with GF 3.0. That also helped quite a bit. 

I've also have to admit I was a tiny bit stressed as I have a timetable on my end (school), and I never know when all the enterprise pieces will fall on place.

Comment: @user294937: You're welcome. And glad you found some of my other answers also helpful. Thanks for the feedback.